# Submitting a Picture of the Week Photograph that is not your Photograph?

Tags: discussion, featured-photo

I have a photo that is licensed under Creative Commons (attribution only) and I have made some changes to the photo but it is not my work. Is that allowed to be submitted for Picture of the Week?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's really not in the spirit of the contest.  We can't possibly check all the photos but I'd strongly encourage that the photos be fully original works.

If there's something about the photo that you particularly like, perhaps you could use that as inspiration for your own work.